# Create several data.frames via a for loop and name them accordingly

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

I want to apply a for-loop to every element of a list (station code of air quality stations) and create a single data.frame for each station with specific data.

My current code looks like this:

```
for (i in Stations))
{i_PM <- data.frame(PM2.5$DateTime,PM2.5$i)
colnames(i_PM)[1] <- "DateTime"
i_AOT <- subset(MOD2011, MOD2011$Station_ID==i)
i <- merge(i_PM, i_AOT, by="DateTime")}
```

Stations consists of 28 elements. The result should be a data.frame for every station with the colums DateTime, PM2.5 and several elements from MOD2011.

I just dont get it running as its supposed to be. Im sure its my fault, I couldnt find the specific answer via the internet.
Can you show me my mistake?

Comment: Your code is not reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

Try `assign`:

```
for (i in Stations)) {
    dat <- data.frame(PM2.5$DateTime,PM2.5$i)
    dat2 <- subset(MOD2011, MOD2011$Station_ID==i)
    colnames(i_PM)[1] <- "DateTime"
    assign(paste(i, "_PM", sep=""), dat)
    assign(paste(i, "_AOT", sep=""), dat2)
    assign(i, merge(dat, dat2, by="DateTime"))
}
```

Note, however, that this is bad coding practice. You should reconsider your algorithm. For instance, use a list instead.